# Storing a command into a variable?

Tags: linux, shell

```
clock=date "+%d %b %Y:%H:%M:%S %s"
echo "Welcome ! it is now: \n"
echo $clock
```

The `clock` variable doesn't actually get the output from the `date` command as I would expect. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a command output into a variable you need to use the `var=$(command)` syntax. Hence, it will work if you use:

```
clock=$(date "+%d %b %Y:%H:%M:%S %s")
echo -e "Welcome ! it is now: \n"
echo $clock
```

Also,

- to have the new line printed you need to specify `echo -e`.
- the `%H:%M:%S` date format can be reduced to `%T`.

All together it can be:

```
printf "Welcome ! it is now: \n%s\n" "$(date "+%d %b %Y:%T %s")"
```

Comment: `-e` is only necessary in `bash`, as POSIX `echo` (which has no standard options) should treat `\n` as a newline. `printf "Welcome! it is now: %s\n" "$(date ...)"` would be preferred in place of `echo`.

Comment: Really should be `echo "$clock"` to avoid string-splitting and glob-expansion. (Sure, they won't necessarily be harmful in this case, but they're still unnecessary overhead).

Answer (score 0):

also

```
clock=`date "+%d %b %Y:%H:%M:%S %s"`
echo "Welcome ! it is now: \n"
echo $clock
```

Comment: `$()` is preferred over backticks, for readability and ability to nest.